# How can I uninstall pip packages on my mac?

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip, uninstallation

I am trying to run the following command to uninstall pip packages on my mac:

```
pip freeze | xargs sudo pip uninstall -y
```

(even with sudo -H flag, it doesn't work)

`pip freeze` gives me the following list of pip installed packages:
altgraph==0.10.2
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
bonjour-py==0.3
certifi==2017.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
cognitive-face==1.3.1
dill==0.2.7.1
Django==1.11.6
djangorestframework==3.7.1
filemapper==0.1.3
future==0.16.0
idna==2.6
inflection==0.3.1
lxml==3.7.2
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
more-itertools==4.0.1
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.3
ngrams==1.0.3
nltk==3.2.2
numpy==1.8.0rc1
py2app==0.7.3
pyasn1==0.4.2
pygame==1.9.3
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
requests==2.18.4
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==0.13.0b1
SimpleCV==1.3
six==1.4.1
sklearn==0.0
urllib3==1.22
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1

Using `pip freeze | xargs sudo pip uninstall -y`, I get the following result:

```
Uninstalling altgraph-0.10.2:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 346, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.py', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.pyc', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.py', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.pyc', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Dot.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.py', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.pyc', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/Graph.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.py', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.pyc', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphAlgo.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.py', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.pyc', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphStat.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.py', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.pyc', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/GraphUtil.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.pyc', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph/ObjectGraph.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph', '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-YANgl9-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/altgraph'")]
```

It stops uninstalling at the very first package only, doesn't even move to other packages. I tried using `pip uninstall <package-name>` to uninstall packages individually, it still didn't work and gave the same sequence of error statements each time.
I am not aware where I am making a mistake. I want to reset all pip installed packages to start new and install the required packages from scratch.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: When you tried `pip uninstall <package-name>`, did you include the version number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot "sudo pip uninstall" operation not permitted (/tmp) in OS X El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049907/cannot-sudo-pip-uninstall-operation-not-permitted-tmp-in-os-x-el-capitan)

Comment: @nnnmmm no, i just wrote `pip uninstall <package-name>`

Comment: @Adelin In the solution part of your given link, I don't understand the part which says "Source your wrapper from your ~/.bashrc per their docs, and makevirtualenv foo. All other work will be performed in virtual environments only. If you use Python 3, then virtualenv is part of the interpreter, so you don't need virtualenvwrapper and the little dance related to it."
Can you help me understand it?

PS - I am using Python 2.7

Comment: you need to read [their docs](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to understand that

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error and I think you should pass the argument `xargs -n 1` to mention the first block of each row.
Otherwise try to check if it is not a problem specific to your package